# select rows from 2 difrent tables

Tags: php, mysql

have tables like this

```
Table "checklist"
idCardno
name
permAddress
datetime

Table "persons"
name
idcardno
photo
```

now i want my sqlquery be

```
idCardno    |  name    | permAddress   | photo   
-----------------------------------------------
A123456     | John Doe | 302 xyz       | 1.gif
```

the photo should be the corresponding one for the idcardno.

how can i achieve the result like this ? what will my sql query be ?
thanks

Comment: Use a join, WTP? See one of the many questions listed in the Related sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `idCardno <-> idcardno` is the shared key between the two tables and the name you want in output is the one from persons, simply use JOIN:

```
SELECT c.idCardno, p.name, permAddress, photo FROM checklist c JOIN persons p ON c.idCardno = p.idcardno
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select checklist.idCardno as idCardno, checklist.name as name, permAddress, photo
from checklist, persons 
where checklist.idCardno = persons.idCardno
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JOIN

```
SELECT checklist.idCardno, checklist.name, permAddress, photo 
FROM checklist JOIN persons 
ON checklist.idCardno = persons.idcardno
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   C.IDCARDNo
 , C.name
 , C.permAddress
 , P.Photo
FROM checklist C 
INNER JOIN persons P ON C.Idcardno = P.idCardno
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [**JOIN**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

```
select  C.idCardno,
        C.name,
        C.permAddress,
        P.photo   
from checklist C
join persons P
on   C.idCardno=P.idCardno
```

Answer (score 0):

USE JOIN :

```
select 
C.idCardno,C.name,C.permAddress,P.photo   
from checklist C
join persons P
on C.idCardno=P.idCardno
```

Refer Link for reference : [Join](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-joins.htm)

Answer (score 0):

select c.idCardno, c.name,c.permAddress,p.photo from checklist as c left join persons as p on c.idCardno=p.idCardno